# как записать значение в первую ячейку двумерного массива?

Tags: php

Есть массив двумерный массив `$result[$a][$b]`.
У каждого `$a` есть несколько ячеек `$b`.
Мне нужно написать цикл, который бы записывал сначала значение `$a`, потом определенные значения в `$b`
Типа

```
$result[$a]=x;  
$result[$a][b1]=y; 
$result[$a][b2]=z  и т.д.
```

Так вот `$result[$a]=x` не работает.

Подскажите, как правильно записывать в эту ячейку значение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result['a'][] = 'b';
$result['a'][] = 'с';
```